# In Branch SDK for deep linking, Not receiving params data if iOS app launched after Killing

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, ios9, branch.io

I am using Branch SDK for deep linking in iOS; If app running in background and user will tap on link, i am receiving all required params but if app is killed and not running in background then after tapping on link, not receiving params dictionary; Just getting [+is_first_session: 0, +clicked_branch_link: 0]

Please guide in this regards either i am missing to do some thing?

Following is the code snippet:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
        let branch = Branch.getInstance()
        branch.userCompletedAction(BNCAddToCartEvent)
        branch.initSessionWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions) { (params, error) in
            if error == nil
            {
                print("params: \(params.description)")
                if let clickedBranchLink = params[BRANCH_INIT_KEY_CLICKED_BRANCH_LINK] as! Bool? 
                {

                    if clickedBranchLink 
                    {
                        debug_println("CLICKED BRANCH LINK")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you extend your snippet to also show the `continue userActivity` and `open url` calls too?

Comment: @AlexBauer I was making branch.userCompletedAction(BNCAddToCartEvent) call before initialisation of initSessionWithLaunchOptions; Now just moved it down after initSessionWithLaunchOptions; Its working perfectly; Thanks for your response.

Comment: Ah, that would do it! Glad everything is working now